# send INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast from application

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-broadcast

I want to mimic google play com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast.

My app installing another app, when installation finished I want to send the broadcast INSTALL_REFERRER like google play, so the app installed will send the campaign data to google analytics.

I followed all google analytics tutorials, 
and looked on this implemetation also: https://github.com/giago/referraltester

When sending the broadcast from ADB shell everything is working just fine, the analytics receiver receives the data and sends it to Google analytics, sending it from an app seems to be not working.

This is what I get when broadcasting the INSTALL_REFERRER from my app:

**Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.**

The app sending the broadcast:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER");
        i.setPackage("com.dev.refferer2");
        i.putExtra("referrer",
            "utm_source=apps&utm_medium=apps&utm_term=apps&utm_content=apps&utm_campaign=apps");
        sendBroadcast(i);
```

the app receiving the broadcast:
Manifest.xml:

```
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

App:

```
 synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);

        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

MyActivity:

```
    Tracker t = ((App) getApplication()).getTracker(App.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    t.setScreenName("MyActivity");
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

please help me to resolve this issue.
is it even possible or I'm wasting my time here?

thanks!! :)

Comment: I'd like to do the same thing - did you ever get it working??

Comment: Is it possible the application expects the referrer to be encoded? What app are you trying to interact with?

Comment: Hi, did you get it working ?!